# Top Dense_Rank row based on other fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have several tables tied together in sql that I am trying to display only the MAX number from a column formulated using `DENSE RANK` but I need to keep in mind 2 other fields when pulling the TOP row.

Here is a sample of my result:
     **|  sa_id  | price | threshold |      role_id | rk**
  1 |  37E41 | 40.00 |        NULL |  A38D67A |  1
  2 |  37E41 | 40.00 |        NULL |  46B9D4E |  1
  3 | 1CFC1 | 40.00 |        NULL |  58C1E03 |  1
  4 | BF0D3 | 40.00 |        NULL |  28D465B |  1
  5 | F914B  | 40.00 |        NULL |  2920EBD |  1
  6 | F3CA1 | 40.00 |        NULL |   D5E7584 |  1
  7 | 0D8C1 | 40.00 |        NULL | EECDB5A |  1
  8 | A6503  | 40.00 |        NULL |  B680CB4 |  1
  9 | 9BB96  | 40.00 |          0.01 |  D66E612 |  1
10 | 9BB96  | 40.00 |        20.03 |  D66E612 |  2
11 | 9BB96  | 40.00 |        40.03 |  D66E612 |  3
12 | 9BB96  | 40.00 |        60.03 |  D66E612 |  4
13 | 9BB96  | 40.00 |        80.03 |  D66E612 |  5

What I am hoping to accomplish is to display all columns in this screenshot using the highest value for rk (calculated using `DENSE RANK`) where *price > threshold* and the sa_id & role_id are unique.

In this case I would want to display the following rows only: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10

Is this possible?

```
SELECT 
   servicerate_audit_id                 as sa_id
  ,ticket_price                         as price
  ,threshold_threshold/100.00           as threshold
  ,charge_role.chargerole_id            as role_id
  ,DENSE_RANK() OVER(
    PARTITION BY threshold_audit_id
    ORDER BY
        ISNULL(threshold_threshold,9999999), 
        threshold_threshold
        )                               as rk
FROM sts_service_charge_rate
   INNER JOIN ts_threshold
     ON threshold_id = servicerate_threshold_id
   INNER JOIN ts_charge_role as charge_role
     ON chargerole_id = servicerate_charge_role_id
```

Answer (score 0):

#### If you can modify your original query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT 
     servicerate_audit_id                 as sa_id
    ,ticket_price                         as price
    ,threshold_threshold/100.00           as threshold
    ,charge_role.chargerole_id            as role_id
    ,DENSE_RANK() OVER(
      PARTITION BY threshold_audit_id
      ORDER BY
          ISNULL(threshold_threshold,9999999), 
          threshold_threshold
          )                               as rk
    ,DENSE_RANK() OVER(
      ORDER BY
          ISNULL(threshold_threshold,9999999) DESC, 
          threshold_threshold DESC
          )                               as rk_inverse
  FROM sts_service_charge_rate
     INNER JOIN ts_threshold
       ON threshold_id = servicerate_threshold_id
     INNER JOIN ts_charge_role as charge_role
       ON chargerole_id = servicerate_charge_role_id
) t
WHERE price > COALESCE(threshold, 0)
AND t.rk_inverse = 1
```

Observe I just added an inverse calculation of your ranking and filtered for the top `rk_inverse` per partition. I'm assuming that the `PARTITION BY threshold_audit_id` and your requirement of having unique `(sa_id, role_id)` tuples are functionally dependent. Otherwise, your `rk_inverse` calculation would need to take into consideration a different `PARTITION BY` clause.

#### If you cannot modify your original query:

You can calculate another window function that orders your `rk` values descendingly (highest first) per your partition `(sa_id, role_id)`, and then take only the top one per partition:

```
SELECT sa_id, price, threshold, role_id, rk
FROM (
  SELECT result.*, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY sa_id, role_id ORDER BY rk DESC) rn
  FROM (... original query ...)
  WHERE price > COALESCE(threshold, 0)
) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much Lukas. I elegant (and working) solution. I spent days trying to wrap my head around this. I really appreciate all of your help.